# Verify that base class method is called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I need to verify that a class method calls base class method.
Here is the code structure

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual void MethodA()
    {    
    }
}
```

And class that needs to be tested

```
public abstract class MainClass : BaseClass
{
    public void MethodB()
    {    
        base.MethodA();
    }
}
```

I want to write a test that would verify that when I call MainClass.MethodB() then BaseClass.MethodA() gets called.
Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Add a Console.WriteLine("MethodA() was called");

EventLogs works too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog?view=net-5.0

Comment: OP wants to verify this programmatically as part of a unit test. Please pay close attention to the tags they used on the question: `[unit-testing]` and `[moq]` (a mocking library).